# GRPC prbc.h classes not generated objective-c

Tags: objective-c, react-native, cocoapods, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to use GRPC with react native. While basic helloWorld example is working fine with it. When i Added new request to hellowWorld.proto file its is not generating/updating Helloworld.prbc.h file.

helloworld.proto

```
  syntax = "proto3";

  option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

  package helloworld;

  // The greeting service definition.
  service Greeter {
      // Sends a greeting
      rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
      rpc HelloDev (HelloDevRequest) returns (HelloDevReply) {}
  }

  // The request message containing the user's name.
  message HelloRequest {
      string name = 1;
  }

  // The response message containing the greetings
  message HelloReply {
      string message = 1;
  }

  // The request message containing the user's name.
  message HelloDevRequest {
      string name = 1;
  }

  // The response message containing the greetings
  message HelloDevReply {
      string message = 1;
  }
```

I tried:

```
pod install
```

after pod install i was expecting Helloworld.prbc.h to have defination for HelloDev.
Another way:

```
protoc --objc_out=Pods/ReactNativeGrpc --objcgrpc_out=Pods/ReactNativeGrpc helloworld.proto
```

ReactNativeGrpc is pod for my project

here is auto generated file from compiler (its same even after running pod install)

```
// Code generated by gRPC proto compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
        // source: helloworld.proto

        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

        #if !defined(GPB_GRPC_FORWARD_DECLARE_MESSAGE_PROTO) || !GPB_GRPC_FORWARD_DECLARE_MESSAGE_PROTO
        #import "Helloworld.pbobjc.h"
        #endif

        #if !defined(GPB_GRPC_PROTOCOL_ONLY) || !GPB_GRPC_PROTOCOL_ONLY
        #import <ProtoRPC/ProtoService.h>
        #import <ProtoRPC/ProtoRPCLegacy.h>
        #import <RxLibrary/GRXWriteable.h>
        #import <RxLibrary/GRXWriter.h>
        #endif

        @class HLWHelloReply;
        @class HLWHelloRequest;

        #if !defined(GPB_GRPC_FORWARD_DECLARE_MESSAGE_PROTO) || !GPB_GRPC_FORWARD_DECLARE_MESSAGE_PROTO
        #endif

        @class GRPCUnaryProtoCall;
        @class GRPCStreamingProtoCall;
        @class GRPCCallOptions;
        @protocol GRPCProtoResponseHandler;
        @class GRPCProtoCall;


        NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

        @protocol HLWGreeter2 <NSObject>

        #pragma mark SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply)

        /**
         * Sends a greeting
         */
        - (GRPCUnaryProtoCall *)sayHelloWithMessage:(HLWHelloRequest *)message responseHandler:(id<GRPCProtoResponseHandler>)handler callOptions:(GRPCCallOptions *_Nullable)callOptions;

        @end

        /**
         * The methods in this protocol belong to a set of old APIs that have been deprecated. They do not
         * recognize call options provided in the initializer. Using the v2 protocol is recommended.
         */
        @protocol HLWGreeter <NSObject>

        #pragma mark SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply)

        /**
         * Sends a greeting
         *
         * This method belongs to a set of APIs that have been deprecated. Using the v2 API is recommended.
         */
        - (void)sayHelloWithRequest:(HLWHelloRequest *)request handler:(void(^)(HLWHelloReply *_Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error))handler;

        /**
         * Sends a greeting
         *
         * This method belongs to a set of APIs that have been deprecated. Using the v2 API is recommended.
         */
        - (GRPCProtoCall *)RPCToSayHelloWithRequest:(HLWHelloRequest *)request handler:(void(^)(HLWHelloReply *_Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error))handler;


        @end


        #if !defined(GPB_GRPC_PROTOCOL_ONLY) || !GPB_GRPC_PROTOCOL_ONLY
        /**
         * Basic service implementation, over gRPC, that only does
         * marshalling and parsing.
         */
        @interface HLWGreeter : GRPCProtoService<HLWGreeter2, HLWGreeter>
        - (instancetype)initWithHost:(NSString *)host callOptions:(GRPCCallOptions *_Nullable)callOptions NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
        + (instancetype)serviceWithHost:(NSString *)host callOptions:(GRPCCallOptions *_Nullable)callOptions;
        // The following methods belong to a set of old APIs that have been deprecated.
        - (instancetype)initWithHost:(NSString *)host;
        + (instancetype)serviceWithHost:(NSString *)host;
        @end
        #endif

        NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

PodFile:

```
      platform :ios, '9.0'

  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

  def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
    versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
    versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
    versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
    versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
    versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
    versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

    pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

    # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
    # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
    pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
    pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  end

  # Post Install processing for Flipper
  def flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'YogaKit'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  target 'Hello' do
    # Pods for Hello
    pod 'ReactNativeGrpc', :path => '.'
    pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
    pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
    pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
    pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
    pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
    pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
    pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
    pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
    pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
    pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
    pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
    pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
    pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
    pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

    pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
    pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
    pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
    pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
    pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
    pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
    pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
    pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

    target 'HelloTests' do
      inherit! :complete
      # Pods for testing
    end

    use_native_modules!

    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable these next few lines.
    add_flipper_pods!
    post_install do |installer|
      flipper_post_install(installer)
    end
  end

  target 'Hello-tvOS' do
    # Pods for Hello-tvOS

    target 'Hello-tvOSTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      # Pods for testing
    end
  end
```

ReactNativeGRPC.Podspec:

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name     = "ReactNativeGrpc"
    s.version  = "0.0.1"
    s.license  = "Apache License, Version 2.0"
    s.authors  = { 'gRPC contributors' => 'grpc-io@googlegroups.com' }
    s.homepage = "https://grpc.io/"
    s.summary = "Example integration between react-native and GRPC"
    s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git' }

    s.ios.deployment_target = "7.1"
    s.osx.deployment_target = "10.9"

    # Base directory where the .proto files are.
    src = "../proto"

    # Run protoc with the Objective-C and gRPC plugins to generate protocol messages and gRPC clients.
    s.dependency "!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin", "~> 1.0"

    # Pods directory corresponding to this app's Podfile, relative to the location of this podspec.
    pods_root = 'Pods'

    # Path where Cocoapods downloads protoc and the gRPC plugin.
    protoc_dir = "#{pods_root}/!ProtoCompiler"
    protoc = "#{protoc_dir}/protoc"
    plugin = "#{pods_root}/!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin/grpc_objective_c_plugin"

    # Directory where the generated files will be placed.
    dir = "#{pods_root}/#{s.name}"

    s.prepare_command = <<-CMD
      mkdir -p #{dir}
      #{protoc} \
          --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=#{plugin} \
          --objc_out=#{dir} \
          --grpc_out=#{dir} \
          -I #{src} \
          -I #{protoc_dir} \
          #{src}/helloworld.proto
    CMD

    # Files generated by protoc
    s.subspec "Messages" do |ms|
      ms.source_files = "#{dir}/*.pbobjc.{h,m}", "#{dir}/**/*.pbobjc.{h,m}"
      ms.header_mappings_dir = dir
      ms.requires_arc = false
      # The generated files depend on the protobuf runtime.
      ms.dependency "Protobuf"
    end

    # Files generated by the gRPC plugin
    s.subspec "Services" do |ss|
      ss.source_files = "#{dir}/*.pbrpc.{h,m}", "#{dir}/**/*.pbrpc.{h,m}"
      ss.header_mappings_dir = dir
      ss.requires_arc = true
      # The generated files depend on the gRPC runtime, and on the files generated by protoc.
      ss.dependency "gRPC-ProtoRPC"
      ss.dependency "#{s.name}/Messages"
    end

    s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      # This is needed by all pods that depend on Protobuf:
      'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => '$(inherited) GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1',
      # This is needed by all pods that depend on gRPC-RxLibrary:
      'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES',
    }
  end
```

Want to use updated proto definition in code, that's not working here.

Edit 1: Cleaning and installing every time works but need alternative to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clean Cocoapods cache? If not, try to run the following command to clean cache before running `pod install`:

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf (your_project).xcworkspace
rm Podfile.lock
```

Comment: It works but I have to do this every time the proto file updates. I am trying to avoid that.